# How to read this PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I juste want to know how to read the value "status" in this PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [smsId] => 10124
            [numberFrom] => +000
            [numberTo] => +000
            [status] => waiting
            [date] => 20100825184048
            [message] => ACK/
            [text] => Test
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [smsId] => 10125
            [numberFrom] => +000
            [numberTo] => +000
            [status] => waiting
            [date] => 20100825184049
            [message] => ACK/
            [text] => Test 2
        )

)
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353197/foreach-and-2d-array-in-php read this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you have an array of objects. So you have to use a combination of array and object syntax to get your value:

```
$array[0]->status;
```

this breaks down into:

```
$object = $array[0]; // Array Syntax
$status = $object->status; // Object Syntax
$status = $array[0]->status; // Combined Array & Object Syntax
```

If you need to access each status in a loop, you do something like:

```
foreach($array as $obj){
    $status = $obj->status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$arr is the array you've got there.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
   echo $arr[$i]->status;
}
```

Please take a look in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
 echo $arr->status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If array variable is **$arr**

```
$arr[0]->status;
$arr[1]->status;
```