# Echo looped Multidimension Array Values

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to use the for each loop to access and retrive the multidimensional array values

```
<?php
    $contents = array(
       "slide1" => array("title" => "My Digital Life",
                         "description" => "http://www.mydigitallife.info"
                         ),
       "slide2" => array("title" => "My Digital Life",
                         "description" => "http://www.mydigitallife.info"
                         ),
    );

?>
```

Goal for output

```
<ul>
    <li this will be slide1 output>
       <h1><?php echo [title]; ?></h1>
       <p><?php echo [description]; ?></p>
    </li>
    <li this will be slide2 output>
       <h1><?php echo [title]; ?></h1>
       <p><?php echo [description]; ?></p>
    </li>
    <li and so on, depending on the php array>
       <h1><?php echo [title]; ?></h1>
       <p><?php echo [description]; ?></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Sorry guys, I forget too add my attempt which isnt working + the loop is static too 3, i need it to be dynamic to the amount of slides in the array.

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++)
{
echo "<li>Title: ".$slider[$row]["title"]." Description ".$slider[$row]["description"]."</li>";
echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353197/foreach-and-2d-array-in-php Try looking at that, it might help?

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($contents as $slide => $info): ?>
    <li>
        <h1> <?=$info['title']?> </h1>
        <p> <?=$info['description']?> </p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply nest foreach loops:

```
foreach ($contents as $contentKey => $contentArr) {
  // output <li>
  echo '<li>';
  foreach ($contentArr as $singleContentKey => $singleContent ) {
    switch ($singleContentKey){
      case 'title':
        // output h1
        echo sprintf('<h1>%s</h1>',$singleContent );
        break;
      case 'description':
        // output p
        echo sprintf('<p>%s</p>',$singleContent );
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  // close </li>
  echo '</li>';
}
```

To manipulate content base on nested array key i suggest using switch .. case statement.

And what was said already in comments - you should put at least a little effort to solve problems by yourself and if you did - explain what have you done so far.

Comment: I am sort of new to `php`, how exactly can I output the title or the description (what is the proper syntax too access it from the array.

Comment: Edited answer with echoes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the foreach loop to loop through the multidimensional array and retrieve the value as mentioned in the question.

```
$arr = yourarray()



foreach($arr as $array)
{
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo '<p>'.$key.' => '.$value.'</p>';
}
}
```

If this is not you wanted ..please post what you need as a comment below